# Strange class creation in PHP

Tags: php

I'm working on some PHP code and came across this line, and I'm not sure what the syntax means.

```
$someclass = (new SomeClass())->someMethod(10);
```

What is happening here? I'm use to seeing classes being instantiated, and methods being called like this:

`$someclass = new SomeClass();` 
`$someClass->someMethod(10);`

Comment: Both are the same thing i think..!

Comment: The object is being initiated and method is being called at once.

Comment: The name of the variable `$someClass` is misleading, instead of the new created object it will contain the result of the method `someMethod()`. This is an excellent example, why one should carefully choose variable names and try to write readable code.

Answer (score 2):

The class is initiated but there is no reference kept to use the class later. $someClass will contain the value returned by someMethod(10).

Answer (score 2):

That's simply shorthand notation for the same thing. Say you need to call method `bar` of class `Foo`. To do so, you need to instantiate `Foo`:

```
$foo  = new Foo;
$data = $foo->bar();
```

But you really have no interest in `$foo`, you just want `$data`. The shorthand syntax just instantiates the class and then calls the method, without needing to create and keep the variable `$foo`:

```
$data = (new Foo)->bar();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can only do that in php >= 5.4.

The class is instantiated, and then `someMethod` is called on the new instance. Then the result of `someMethod` function is stored into `$someclass`. (The title of this variable is misleading, by the way)

Quick test:

```
<?php
class SomeClass {
    public function someMethod($val) {
        return $val * 42;
    }
}

$someclass = (new SomeClass())->someMethod(10);
var_dump($someclass);
```

Output: `int(420)`

http://ideone.com/Vebt4d

Answer (score 0):

`new SomeClass()` returns a pointer to a new instance of the class.  Rather than assigning that to a variable, the code calls a method in the newly formed instance and returns the value.  A handle to the new instance is not kept.  If it were C++ it would leak memory, but I'm pretty sure PHP will clean up right away..

Answer (score 0):

This is the same as:

```
$object1 = new SomeClass();
$someclass = $object1->someMethod(10);
```

The `$someclass` should be the return value of `someMethod`. The actual value and class depends on how `someMethod` is written.

In some practice, `someMethod` may return the object instance itself. But it is not a must. Please read `someMethod` carefully.